# Pause the Flow-player once a JavaScript function is called.

Tags: php, flowplayer, resume

I am using *flowplayer* to display videos in my project. I am using the following code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>secure/<?php echo $videos->videolink?>" class="fplayer" id="flowplayer">
</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('div[id^="overlay_form"]').css({ 

            left: ($(window).width() - $('div[id^="overlay_form"]').width()) / 2,
            top: ($(window).width() - $('div[id^="overlay_form"]').width()) / 7,
            position:'fixed'
            });

});
</script>
<script>

$f("flowplayer", "<?php echo base_url()?>js/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
  clip: {

    autoPlay : "true",
    autoBuffering : "true",
    onStart: function() {

          //msgs.innerHTML += "Common Clip event listener called\n";
          return true;
      },

      onPause: function() {
          //msgs.innerHTML = "Paused";
      },

      onResume: function() {
          resumingvideo();
      }
  },

  });
</script>
```

and it is working fine. I have a span which will display a popup and the function for it is

```
function showpop(id)
{
    $("#overlay_form"+id).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

*CSS for the popup:*

```
div[id^="overlay_form"]{
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid #79BAEC;
border-radius:5px;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
width: 270px;
height: 180px;
}
```

While this popup is coming, it is getting displayed at the back of the videoplayer since the video is getting played like shown in the image below.
[image]

Once the video is paused, the popup will come in the correct place. So is there any way to show the popup while playing the video and also what should I do to pause the video once `showpop()` function is called ? I want the popup to be come like shown below:

[image]

Can anyone help me to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to also edit flowplayer css may be this also using absolute poition and z-index

Comment: how can I pause the video inside the js function showpop() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1.

For the popup try setting the `wmode` to opaque.  This will allow the player to respect z-indexes.

**Example taken from flowplayer site**

```
flowplayer("player", {
    src:"http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf",
    wmode: "opaque" // This allows the HTML to hide the flash content
    }, {
    clip: {
      url: 'http://stream.flowplayer.org/flowplayer-700.flv'
    }
});
```

For more detailed info see the flowplayer [wmode demo](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/wmode.html)

### 2.

To pause the video you should be able to do something like this in your showpop function.

```
$f("player").pause();
```

See [player docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html) for more info on this.